# React Native webview is not caching .js .css files

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-ios

Despite the fact that server responds with proper caching headers the RN WebView doesn't seem to respect them. It always requests the files from the server.

```
Last-Modified   Fri, 25 May 2018 12:25:24 GMT
ETag    "5b0800b4-2897f3"
Expires Sun, 24 Jun 2018 17:17:50 GMT
Cache-Control   max-age=2592000
Pragma  public
Cache-Control   public
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=15768000
```

Looking into the API of the WebView it doesn't seem to expose any settings to tweak the configuration. The funny part is that caching works fine for images served by the same server with the same set of headers.